# FileNotFoundException al usar http://user:password@dominio.com

Tags: java, android, http, url

Estoy intentando acceder a un archivo que tengo en un servidor, el cual está protegido con un `.htpasswd`. Y al intentar acceder desde mi app en `android` me aparece la siguiente excepción:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://User:Password@dominio.com/configuracion.xml

El código que utilizo es:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);

// Read all the text returned by the server
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str = in.readLine();
in.close();
```

Comment: Obviamente si el archivo esta protegido no lo puedes abrir asi.

Comment: Si lo hago desde el navegador si funciona, porque desde java no? @Lithorell

Comment: En java estas utilizando un flujo, por eso funciona distinto.

Comment: Y sabes si es posible desde java¿? @Lithorell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724576/read-remote-file-in-java-which-needs-username-and-password

Comment: Sabes como puedo añadir este `classpath` => `commons-vfs.jar`
`commons-logging.jar` ??? Me da error @Lithorell

Comment: Depende como tengas configurado el proyecto. Si usas librerias sueltas tendras que añadirlas al buildpath, mientras que si usas maven tendras que incluirlas en el pom.

Comment: Utilizo librerias sueltas en el build.gradle @Lithorell

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60756/discussion-between-samsung-developer-and-lithorell). @Lithorell

Comment: build.gradle no lo he usado nunca, en eso no te puedo ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso de agregar el usuario y password en la url `http://user:password@dominio.com` es un atajo un poco sucio que solo algunos navegadores implementan (y parece que cada vez menos). No se recomienda. Y es logico que en Java no ande.

Para conectarse con HTTP con autenticación (Basic), hay [varias maneras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java), pero todas se resuelven a codificar el string `<usuario>:<clave>` en Base64 y agregarlo como property `"Authorization"` en la conexión:

```
URL url = new URL(path);
String userPass = "username:password";
String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userPass.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
//o String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(userPass.getBytes(), Base64.No_WRAP));
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
urlConnection.connect();
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Y para leer un xml mediante parser sax??

Comment: Pues le pasas el input stream al parser, imagino yo. Cual es el problema?